# SQL Server T-SQL - Optimizing Stuff String Function

Tags: sql-server

Using Stuff function to concatenate 7 days data in comma separated as a column it takes time more than usual db is under load on daily basis and this query is used for the mobile app user means alot of users calling this query or is there any other way to show date column in comma separated which is more optimal. SQL SERVER VersionMicrosoft SQL Server 2014 (SP2) (KB3171021) - 12.0.5000.0 (X64)
Jun 17 2016 19:14:09
Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation
Enterprise Edition: Core-based Licensing (64-bit) on Windows NT 6.3  (Build 9600: )

```
STUFF((SELECT ',' + CAST(slotdate AS nvarchar(20))
       FROM dbo.OSlotAvailable t1
       WHERE t1.ResourceID = a.ResourceID
         AND ((@Date IS NULL
           AND SlotDate >= CAST(GETDATE() AS date)
           AND SlotDate < DATEADD(DAY, 7, CAST(GETDATE() AS date)))
           OR (SlotDate >= @Date
           AND SlotDate < DATEADD(DAY, 7, @Date)))
       GROUP BY SlotDate,
                ResourceID
       ORDER BY t1.SlotDate
       FOR XML PATH('')),1,LEN(','),'');
```

Comment: All `STUFF` is doing here is removing characters from the start of a string; that can't really be optimised. It is more likely you want your query with `FOR XML PATH` optimised.

Comment: If you're on a fully supported version of SQL Server, then you could use `STRING_AGG`, which may be more performant, depending on the rest of the query.

Comment: If you have an index on `ResourceID,SlotDate` you may find `WHERE t1.ResourceID = a.ResourceID AND SlotDate >= ISNULL(@Date, CAST(GETDATE() AS date)) AND SlotDate < DATEADD(DAY, 7, ISNULL(@Date, CAST(GETDATE() AS date))))` performs better than your current `WHERE` clause.  `OR` is often problematic.

Comment: Thanks for the response yes there are indexing on where clause and or is must as per requirement

Comment: String_agg function isn't available if I can get the logic of this function I can create a user define function and that could help

Comment: The suggested rewrite returns the same results as using or so how can or be a requirement?

Comment: The or statement is there because if we pass a specific date to sp then it takes data from that day to the next 7 days and if this date parmeter is null then it takes current date to next 7 days

Comment: Thats what my rewrite does without using OR

Comment: Thanks sir Sorry I didn't Read the rewrite got it thanks